# Mysql query failed after adding category table

Tags: mysql

When i run this query i'm keeping getting this error `Database query failed 1054 - Unknown column 'cv.employeeIDFK' in 'on clause'`

This only happen when I add the category in my query 
    FROM opjb_cv AS cv , opjb_cvCategory AS cv_cat 
    AND cv_cat.categoryIDFK IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,11,22,24,26,28 ) 
    AND cv_cat.cvIDFK = cv.id

This is my query which is failing as you can see i have added all information but still its failing i cant seem to find anything wrong with this.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT cv.id, cv.targetJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitleAlt, cv.recentEmployer, employee.firstName, 
employee.surname, cv.recentJobTitle, cv.modifyAt, cv.city, cv.countryCountyFK, cv.countryStatesFK, cv.countryISO2FK, cv.experienceIDFK, 
cv.careerIDFK, cv.areYouAuth, country.countryName, cv.employeeIDFK as user_id , 
match ( cv.title, cv.recentJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitleAlt ) AGAINST ('desktop' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 

    FROM opjb_cv AS cv , opjb_cvCategory AS cv_cat 

    JOIN opjb_employee AS employee ON cv.employeeIDFK = employee.id 
    JOIN opjb_country AS country ON cv.countryISO2FK=country.iso2 
    JOIN opjb_experience AS experience ON cv.experienceIDFK = experience.id 
    JOIN opjb_type AS type ON cv.jobTypeIDFK = type.id 
    JOIN opjb_education AS education ON cv.educationIDFK = education.id 
    JOIN opjb_countryStates as countryStates ON cv.countryStatesFK = countryStates.code 

    WHERE cv.showTo=1 
    AND cv.status=1 
    AND cv.countryISO2FK='GB' 
    AND match ( cv.title, cv.recentJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitleAlt ) AGAINST ('desktop' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) 
    AND cv_cat.categoryIDFK IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,11,22,24,26,28 ) 
    AND cv_cat.cvIDFK = cv.id 
    AND experience.id=5 
    AND type.id=1 
    AND education.id=7 
    AND cv.modifyAt > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND ( cv.salaryMin <= 48000 OR cv.salaryMax <= 48000 ) 
    AND cv.countryStatesFK ='EG' 
    ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

These are all the tables which is involde in this query.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opjb_country` (
  `iso2` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `iso3` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `isoNo` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
  `countryName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `regionIDFK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`iso2`),
  KEY `regionIDFK` (`regionIDFK`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `opjb_countryStates`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opjb_countryStates` (
  `code` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
  `name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `countryISO2FK` char(2) NOT NULL default 'US',
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`code`,`countryISO2FK`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `opjb_cv`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opjb_cv` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `fileName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fileType` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `fileExe` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `fileSize` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `filePath` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `originalName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fileHash` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `showTo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `defaultCV` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `targetJobTitle` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `targetJobTitleAlt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `educationIDFK` int(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `careerIDFK` int(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `areYouAuth` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `recentJobTitle` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `recentEmployer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `recentIndustry` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `recentCareer` int(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `recentStartDate` date NOT NULL,
  `recentEndDate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `jobTypeIDFK` int(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `jobStatusIDFK` int(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `salaryMin` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `salaryMax` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `salaryCurrency` varchar(5) NOT NULL default 'GBP',
  `salaryType` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '5',
  `relocate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `willing_to_travel` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  `availability` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `startDate` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `positions` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `userComments` text,
  `noViews` int(7) NOT NULL default '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `adminComments` text,
  `employeeIDFK` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `countryISO2FK` char(2) NOT NULL default 'US',
  `countryStatesFK` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `countryCountyFK` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `experienceIDFK` int(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `modifyAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `employeeIDFK` (`employeeIDFK`),
  KEY `countryISO2FK` (`countryISO2FK`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `searchCV` (`title`,`targetJobTitle`,`targetJobTitleAlt`,`recentJobTitle`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `opjb_cvCategory`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opjb_cvCategory` (
  `cvIDFK` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `categoryIDFK` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`cvIDFK`,`categoryIDFK`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `opjb_education`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opjb_education` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `educationName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(50) NOT NULL default 'english',
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `opjb_employee`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opjb_employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `emailAddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `middleName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `countryCountyFK` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `countryStatesFK` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `countryISO2FK` char(2) NOT NULL default 'US',
  `postCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `careerStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `contPref` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `webSite` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `recent_employer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `home_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `categoryIDFK` int(6) default NULL,
  `careerDegreeIDFK` int(6) default NULL,
  `educationIDFK` int(6) default NULL,
  `experienceIDFK` int(6) default NULL,
  `pers_statement` text,
  `actKey` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `lastVisit` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modifyAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createip` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `loginip` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `emailAddress` (`emailAddress`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `city` (`city`,`countryCountyFK`),
  KEY `countryISO2FK` (`countryISO2FK`),
  KEY `idx_fullname` (`firstName`,`surname`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `opjb_experience`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opjb_experience` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `experienceName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(50) NOT NULL default 'english',
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `opjb_type`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opjb_type` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `typeName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(50) NOT NULL default 'english',
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: I think adding a schema dump to your question will help

Comment: i dont know what schema dump is

Comment: the table structure, eg: the CREATE TABLE SQL for each of the tables used in the query.

Comment: sorry you wont all the tables

Comment: it might help to answer your question, yes.

Comment: I added all the tables

Comment: I have find a soluction i forgot to add the JOIN cvCategory AS cv_cat ON  cv_cat.cvIDFK = cv.id. its working fine. thank you